# Is there a shortcut to run only one line on vs-code Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Something similar to Something similar to Cmd+Shift+Enter on Google Colab where only the selected line is run?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: see subsequent answer for a more complete solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76373046/21896093)

**Update 2**: Answer was deleted by mod. See this similar post for how I send a selection to the terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76372810/21896093

I think this would be a nice feature. An alternative that I have been using is to have an interactive console open when I'm in notebook mode; i.e. I have both the notebook pane, and an additional interactive IPython terminal.

I use the interactive terminal as a scratchpad, and for running individual lines or parts of lines. I do this by copying the line/selection I want to run, Ctrl+2 to switch to the interactive console, and paste/exec the line segment in there.

I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6484

Similar/duplicate GH issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4573

Ideally I'd be able to execute the selection from the notebook, but until that feature is available, I've been using an additional interactive terminal. I have recently migrated to native notebooks, having previously worked from Python scripts in Interactive mode, so I am used to having an interactive console always open.

Another poster has asked about this feature on SO: [Running a Single Line in a Python Notebook in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981918/run-only-partial-or-a-single-line-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-running-a-python)

Comment: Here I made a feature request to run selection: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200625 If you like it, please support by giving it a 