# Running a Single Line in a Python Notebook in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Python notebooks in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) and I'm wondering if there is a shortcut or command that allows me to execute only the highlighted line, rather than running the entire code block. In Google Colab, I can achieve this by using the shortcut "Cmd + Shift + Enter" on a Mac.

For instance, let's say I have a code cell where line 2 is highlighted, and I want to run just that specific line without executing the rest of the code block.

I would like to know if there is a similar feature available in VSCode or any other IDEs that allows me to execute individual lines within a code cell in a Python notebook.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches for achieving this selective line execution functionality in VSCode or other IDEs.

Thank you for your assistance and expertise.

Comment: Here I made a feature request to run selection: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200625 If you like it, please support by giving it a 

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.

[image]

1. Select the code what you want to run.

[image]

2. Right click to select Run Code/ Shortcuts "**Ctrl+Alt+N**"/ Triangular button in the upper right corner.

[image]

[image]

3. You can get the result in the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Hi MingJie,  thank you very much for the reply, this does answer my question to some extent but not the exact use case I dictated, I want to run individual  line in a cell and get the output in the notebooks cell output block instead of in the terminal..

Comment: @ArvindReddy Then I think why not split a separate cell directly? Jupyter notebook is designed for this purpose.

Comment: yes @MingJie absolutely, we could create a different cell,  but often times I realised that it will leave the notebook quite messy, and option to run just the selection ( as in Google Colab ) will be very handy

Comment: I think it would be a better choice to submit a request for a new function to developers in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter).

Comment: yes  now that I dint receive any answer to what  I was looking for I will raise a request on git.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: see subsequent answer for a more complete solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76372810/21896093)

I think this would be a nice feature. An alternative that I have been using is to have an interactive console open when I'm in notebook mode; i.e. I have both the notebook pane, and an additional interactive IPython terminal.

I use the interactive terminal as a scratchpad, and for running individual lines or parts of lines. I do this by copying the line/selection I want to run, Ctrl+2 to switch to the interactive console, and paste/exec the line segment in there.

I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6484

Similar/duplicate issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4573

Ideally I'd be able to execute the selection from the notebook, but until that feature is available, I've been using an additional interactive terminal. I have recently migrated to native notebooks, having previously worked from Python scripts in Interactive mode, so I am used to having an interactive console always open.

Another poster has asked about this feature on SO: [Is there a shortcut to run only one line on vs-code Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147194/is-there-a-shortcut-to-run-only-one-line-on-vs-code-jupyter-notebook/)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution for where I want to send a *line or selection* to the terminal.

1. Start up an interactive jupyter terminal as per the previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76343936/21896093
2. Create a keyboard macro that maps this sequence of actions to a single keypress: Ctrl+C (copy) > Ctrl+2 (switches to interactive pane) > Ctrl+V > Ctrl+Enter (runs pasted code) > Ctrl+1 (back to notebook pane).

When no selection is made, the macro will send the line to the terminal (as in VSCode Ctrl+C on a line automatically copies the entire line). When a selection is made, the macro will send that selection the the terminal.

I am using the macro feature that ships with my keyboard. Alternatively, I think VSCode has some extensions that enable you to record a macro, but I haven't tried.